# How to add items that generated through random method to a list and display it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

By using random function it displayed some of random element from list in a container how can i add that specific item into a list and display it as favourites? Please help me with this.

```
List<String> favourites = [];
onLongPress: () {
   setState(() {
         randomIndex = Random().nextInt(hes.length);
         favourites.add(hes[randomIndex].name);
});
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add a random element into a list and display it using listview builder may be

Comment: Please tell me how to create a list and add that element

Comment: list.add(element)

Comment: please check my question and tell me that it's correct way to add element